# Google Cloud Functions Python requests fails

Tags: python, firebase, python-requests, google-cloud-functions

I'm implementing a Google Cloud Function written in Python that I am currently testing on my local emulator in debug mode using `firebase emulators:start --debug`. I need to send multiple https requests to get content from webpages, however my code seems to fail after a few requests, and I can't understand why. Here is a piece of code that produces the error:

```py
import requests 

for i in range(100):
    requests.get("https://apple.com")
```

This does not explicitly crash, however I get the following debug output:

```
functions: Failed to load function definition from source: FirebaseError: User code failed to load. Cannot determine backend specification {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"message":"Failed to load function definition from source: FirebaseError: User code failed to load. Cannot determine backend specification"}}
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Jan/2024 06:19:04] "GET /__/quitquitquit HTTP/1.1" 200 -

/bin/sh: line 1: 64676 Terminated: 15          python3.11 "/Users/myname/Desktop/foldername/functions/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/firebase_functions/private/serving.py
```

I also get the following:

```
[2024-01-16T06:19:35.161Z] Jan 15, 2024 10:19:35 PM io.gapi.emulators.netty.HttpVersionRoutingHandler channelRead
INFO: Detected non-HTTP/2 connection.
 {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"firestore"},"message":"Jan 15, 2024 10:19:35 PM io.gapi.emulators.netty.HttpVersionRoutingHandler channelRead\nINFO: Detected non-HTTP/2 connection.\n"}}
```

Typically my program stops working after 5-10 requests, and it does not seem to depend on the url I am making the requests to, so it does not come from rate limiting. As far as I can tell all the requests are coming back with status code 200.

I anyone has any idea of what could be causing this that would be greatly appreciated. Let me know if you need more information too. Side note: I believe my functions and firebase environment are set up correctly, as everything else works just as expected.

Comment: Review the error message `User code failed to load. Cannot determine backend specification`. Edit and provide details on your code and how you are deploying.

Comment: Also, provide details on how you set up Firebase.

Answer (score 0):

**Add sleep in between requests:**

Create a short delay between your queries using time.Use sleep() to avoid sending requests too soon. This can help keep the emulator from becoming overloaded.

```
import requests
import time

for i in range(100):
    requests.get("https://apple.com")
    time.sleep(1)
```